# Python Aliexpress API promoLinkGenerate

Tags: python-3.x

I'm traying to generate Affiliate links via de Aliexpress API but i could not get any wrapper that's updated or any page that can help me with this.

the only one seams to be 3 years old https://github.com/EitherSoft/python-aliexpress-api-client

Is there any i'm missing?

Comment: Hi. Have you any update on this? I am looking for an updated python wraper for this API and found none even in the https://console.aliexpress.com/app/sdkDownload.htm page is outdated.

Comment: I have a good script for get all the links of affiliate .. contact me 
I can't paste it here .. sorry 

my gmail : miloud.mokkedem@gmail.com